# Xcode version 8.0 storyboard view Controllers messed up automatically

Tags: viewcontroller, ios10, xcode8, xcode-storyboard

The View controllers are automatically messed up itself whenever I open the Xcode daily. I couldn't find that issue. Now I am using IDE Xcode Version 8.0. I didn't get the same issue on Xcode Version 7.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8 has removed the height+width grid. Instead you can view your storyboards as they would be laid out for each compatible device size. Just select one size (e.g. iPhone 7), fix it up once and leave it set to that.

Comment: I couldn't make head nor tail of the OP's question - would you consider submitting a clarification edit? I am wondering whether to vote to close as unclear.